# Best way to compare two integer arrays and find which numbers are not present in second array

Tags: c#

There are solutions out there, some of which uses LINQ as shortcut but I am looking for an optimised and best way in terms of performance and standard, when given two integer arrays, find which numbers are not present in second array w/o using LINQ

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5] -> [1, 3]
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] -> []
```

Comment: What have you done so far to make people here want to help you? Do post a [mcve] of your effort.

Comment: Is the resulting order arbitrary? Or should it be the same as the first array?

Comment: Linq is actually pretty quick for this. You should time any solution that doesn't using Linq and compare it to the trivial Linq solution. Anyway, the fastest algorithm will depend on the relative sizes of the two arrays, which you haven't specified.

Comment: It's a shame you don't want to use linq, with linq it's as simple as `array1.Except(array2);`

Comment: By the way, LINQ isn't just a 'shortcut'. Just because something's easy to use it doesn't necessarily mean you take a hit on efficiency. It's well designed, and it actually compiles (in most, similar, cases) to a loop you'd write 'by hand' anyway. Use LINQ.

Comment: FWIW, [here's what `Except` does under the hood](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,785).  Yes, that's just a couple of `foreach` loops.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Aye, but inside the loops there's a `Set.Add()` which is not trivial... But I still think Linq is likely to be optimal for the general case.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - there has to be doesn't there? How else do you populate the array of differences at the end?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah - it needs some way to keep track of what's going on.  My point was that LINQ isn't some "scary beast", it's just "normal" code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution but I was hoping to get it done better:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = {1,2,3};
        int[] b = {2,4,5};
        FindUniqueItems (a, b);
    }
     private static void FindUniqueItems (int[] a, int[] b) {
        foreach (int i in a){
            if (!Exists(i, b)) {
                Console.WriteLine("unique number: " + i);

            }
        }
    }

    private static bool Exists(int n, int[] b) {
        foreach (int i in b) {
            if (n == i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return
```